# Using grep, how to match beginning of line with pattern from stdin

Tags: regex, grep, pipe

I have a one-liner that prints out a series a numbers:

```
124
132
186
```

I am then piping this output into grep to match these numbers to the beginning of lines in another file but sometimes the second number in the line matches one of the patterns and I get an incorrect match like so:

```
$ get_id_command | grep -f - users.list
124 => 3456, Charles Charmichael, ccharmichael
132 => 2498, Sarah Walker, swalker
186 => 8934, John Casey, jcasey
240 => 1245, Morgan Grimes, mgrimes
```

What options do I need for grep to only match patterns at the beginning of the line? I would really like to keep this as a one-linter.

Comment: Please add users.list to your question. (no comment).

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: My users.list is just over 500 similar lines of the same format as I pasted. My desired output is just like what I pasted but without the `^240` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepend a circumflex to each line of your file and it will work. Circumflex does indicate the line start within the pattern. So modify your `users.list` as described, e.g.

```
sed -Ei 's|(.*)|^\1|' users.list
```

After that you should get the desired result by your command

```
$ get_id_command | grep -f - users.list
```

Comment: Editing the users.list is no-go (it's used by another application which requires that format) and I would like to keep all this within one-line

Comment: But I see that I can keep it a one-liner by doing ` get_id_command | sed -E 's|(.*)|^\1|' | grep -f - users.list`. Thanks!